# Perl GUI programming on Windows

Tags: windows, perl, user-interface

I'm looking for tools for Perl GUI programming on Windows for educational/in-house development, mostly science related.

My first choice was PerlQt. A friend of mine was developing with Qt and C++ so I expected getting some help from him. Also Qt has a GUI creator and Linux has nice integration with Perl. 
Unfortunately, I failed to make it work on Windows.
I searched for other options and am still not clear after search. This is what I've got so far.

- Perl/Tk: broad user base, good documentation, relatively low learning
  curve. But old look and may not be active. Yet some articles say it is rebooted now and has native look.
- wxPerl: native look. But steep learning curve. Not all wx library is ported to Perl. Some like it and some hate it.
- Win32:GUI: native look, can use all Windows API. Needed force install because one of the tests was failed. Still works but not sure it was installed correctly.
- XUL::GUI: using FireFox engine, CSS typing.

I could managed to install them and succeeded to show "Hello, world". Yet, I can't decide which one to go and the online information sometimes looks contradict each other.

Would you compare the tools in terms of human efficiency (easy to read and write codes), computational efficiency and the availability of GUI builder?

Comment: You missed [Prima](http://www.prima.eu.org/). I found a nice introduction of [Prima on Windows](http://blogs.perl.org/users/fabio_dalfonso/2012/07/a-brief-introduction-to-prima.html).

Comment: I see you say "science related". What are you doing with it? David Mertens (and a few others, including myself) are building a PDL-centric REPL using Prima. It has functionality which might be able to contain simple applications as tabs within the main window. [CPAN link](https://metacpan.org/module/DCMERTENS/App-Prima-REPL-0.03/bin/prima-repl), [GitHub link](https://github.com/run4flat/App-Prima-REPL)

Answer (score 14):

For real cross platform GUI programming I would suggest [`Prima`](http://p3rl.org/Prima) or [`Tk`](http://p3rl.org/Tk). Neither look great, but they work.

Still, I think you might be better served (hehe) by using a web front-end than a true GUI these days; this is easy using a web-framework. I would suggest [`Mojolicious`](http://mojolicio.us) though other people do like [`Dancer`](http://perldancer.org). My primary reason for suggesting Mojo over Dancer is that Mojo comes with lots of functionality in one tiny package. Then again, this is the reason that others would recommend Dancer, so that's a toss.

A final consideration is that Mojo comes with WebSockets out of the box. This makes it rather easy for your webapp to feel more like a true application, talking back to the server and getting responses without reloading.

Edit: I now have a good example of a desktop application written with a Perl/Mojo backend and a web-frontent: Azawawi's [`Farabi`](http://p3rl.org/Farabi). It is a text-editor, geared towards writing Perl. It's GUI is the browser, making it a simple cross-platform editor. I recommend it as a starting point for similar tasks.

Answer (score 6):

Self promo for my perl module [IUP](http://search.cpan.org/dist/IUP/) :

- it uses native widgets (= your app will have native look&feel)
- it is also slightly cross-platform (Win32, GTK, Motif)

Comment: Thanks for a wonderful tool, which I have been always looking

Answer (score 2):

There is an outdated [Perl GUI FAQ](http://perlmonks.org/?node_id=108708) on perlmonks.

[PerlQt](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=982634) tracks Qt closely.

Comment: I came across the FAQ. I wasn't sure how much of the info is still valid. The FAQ was written in 2001 with a little bit of updates in 2004. Is most of the info still valid on Windows 7?

Comment: @microbe - I've run PerlTk on windows, other than that, I don't know (Tk, for me, was good for a 1 or 2 window app, but beyond that, I'd probably go with something else). Prima was fairly new at the time the FAQ was written, but it looks still maintained.

Comment: Prima is actively maintained. Dmitry works with us regularly. He is fast to fix bugs too.

Answer (score 2):

I have an experience with PerlTk and wxPerl.
wxPerl is rather decent toolkit which I can recommend. There is also a GUI builder available [wxGlade](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/)

The few applications I had in Tk taught me to hate that toolkit wholeheartedly:

1. it looks awful
2. disproportional amount of coding time was spent on solving various
   bugs and finding workarounds for missing features

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good overview of widget toolkits- many of which provide wrappers to popular programming languages:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits

I recommend `[wxwidgets][1]` aka `wxwindows`, or a browser based solution (e.g. XULrunner) or a pure Javascript+HTML5 based solution. At the moment I am working on a cross-platform tool with only a basic console UI, which then uses websockets and HTML5 + SVG for a more complex UI rendition and UX. To make the web-content dynamic I use a simple template-engine.

( *Personally, for overview questions, I had good experience to put the term `wikipedia` and `list of` somewhere in the search query of ones trusted search engine. Kudos to the diligent wikipedia community.*)

Answer (score 1):

Hta, HTML application, mshta.exe... Old but works like a charm. 
Pros: Total access to basically everything you could want for development of in-house trusted apps. 
Cons: Geometry gets tedious, perlscript (vs vbscript/javascript) documentation/examples are basically nonexistent