# creating a soft ware with UI using python scripts

Tags: python, user-interface

I am planning on creating a software that will be used to analyse biological data, some of us biologists would not have much programming skills yet we do alot of repetitive tasks and are required to write more scripts or programs that we always use using.
i have decided to narrow it down to only one very important task, its a searching script, i.e to query a database of genes-(data), there is already a program that does that called ncbi-blast, usually one needs to be familiar with command line and also requires ubuntu or windows, but its a hassle if you have to analyse the huge quantities of results generated.

so i have want to package some of my python scripts into a software so that others can find it convenient to analyse their work

**Open vs. Closed Source (Licensing)**

i intend to make some of the functionalities freely available to the user in the software, although at a later stage, i intend to incorpaorate pipelines that would require an affordable license

**testing**
so with this one function, it makes testing alot simpler-i dont know yet, and i would not mind starting with linux-ubuntu and windows as the platforms.
I appreciate your advice on choosing just one language, and i will go with python, how ever i would like tyhe software to atleast support other free programs created in other languages like R, as in plugins that a client installs when they need them.
I hope this shades more light to my already complex situation
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're at the beginning of an adventure and some new learning curves.  I will applaud your willingness to create.  Here are some things to consider as you get started on your journey.

fyi: "software" is typically a single word, no space.
Based on the context of "a soft ware" it seems like you mean "application".

I mention "software" and "application" not to give you a hard time about it, but because I think 1) it will help you in future searches when you look for ways to get something done (e.g. you'll get more useful hits on "python application installer" than "python soft ware installer", and 2) you can more clearly explain to people what you are attempting.

So.  Your application(s) will need a user interface for your collection of scripts.  Do you want a graphical user interface (GUI)?  Or a command line interface (CLI)?

**GUI: more complex than CLI:**

For a GUI it will be more complex to get something that runs on both Windows & Linux.
So far as I know there isn't a trivial way to create a single GUI that runs on both Windows & Linux without adding another tool.  Maybe python has easy GUI user-interface stuff in it and you could use that.

For perl I will point you here: "Perl GUI programming on Windows" [Perl GUI programming on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495720/perl-gui-programming-on-windows)
This lists some Perl approaches to consider, you will have to research them and see which ones are also able to run on Linux.  Be careful about including additional libraries you'll need to package (or document how to install) with you application.

**CLI: more simple than a GUI:**

Since they are just scripts today, I would suggest starting with a CLI which probably means cleaning up your argument handling ( @ARGV in Perl, I can't comment on Python).
Read through your code and find literals that you change when you run a script for something new, those things will become your arguments.  And if it starts to seem like you are creating too many arguments maybe you want to look into a configuration file (properties file of some kind).

It will be easier for you to get started with a CLI and you can always come back and add a GUI option in a future release.  I find that designing a well thought out CLI makes it easier to focus on what is important for a GUI so it should help your eventual GUI be even better.

**Packaging**

Packaging your application is going to be a challenge.
Do your scripts need any libraries that aren't part of default with python & perl installs?  If so you need to work out a way to supply those (e.g. include them with your distribution or include documentation that your users can follow to download and install the libs).

I can't comment on pyinstaller.

For Perl I will point you to this question on distributing a Perl Application : [Distributing a Perl Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385759/distributing-a-perl-application#3385860)

**User Skill**

How much skill do you expect your users to have?
Will they be ok with installing a python and perl interpreters if necessary?  Not every user has that technical skill.
Do you want to make sure your scripts verify the minimum versions of python & perl they need?

**Documentation**

See User Skill, above.  You will need to make documentation available.
This will be driven by who is going to use your scripts.  What is your target user like?  Can you write a "5 line" summary that would make me want to download them and try them?  That will be a helpful exercise to help you focus on how you want to present the scripts.

**Open vs. Closed Source (Licensing)**

This also ties into licensing.  Are you aiming for a commercial product?  Giving the world another gift of open source?  Those are both fine things to do, but you'll  want to choose a suitable license for your application.  You also have some work to do if you want to avoid distributing your script's source code (I'm not suggesting you pursue one approach or the other, just that you make the decision before you put it on the internet at large).

**Testing**

Testing your application is going to be a challenge.
If you don't have automated tests for your scripts you will go crazy trying to verify it runs everywhere you want it to run.

Do you have unit tests & test suites for your scripts so you can verify they run correctly on different versions of Windows and various Linux distributions?
If your scripts are pretty simple maybe it doesn't matter if they're running on 32 bit vs. 64 bit operating systems.
Maybe it doesn't matter if they run on Windows 10, Windows 8.x, Windows 7.x, maybe various versions of Windows Server (2012, 2008, ...).
Maybe it doesn't matter if they run on RedHat, Suse, Ubuntu, Mint, ...

You probably want some sanity checks to verify that your install program worked correctly and the environment is suitable.
Without knowing what your scripts do it is kind of hard to say how much testing they benefit from.

**Free Advice: choose just one scripting language and run with that**

I will end with some completely free advice (worth what you're paying for it :-) )

Think **really hard** about just choosing one scripting language and writing everything in that.

You are going to have a LOT of additional complexity from supporting two scripting systems, if I were doing something like you describe I would Seriously Consider consolidating into a single language and just to Python or just do Perl.  The time and energy it takes you to rewrite your Python scripts as Perl (or the other way around) may very well be easier compared to learning about creating installation guides and packaging your application using two different languages.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed feed back, i am certainly realizing how a complex a task it would be if i continued with it. I will address your points here with a lot more background.

Comment: Reading back on this after some sleep I don't want make what could be a fun project seem crazy difficult... I think where you want to be (eventually) is too far to go in one jump.  So - I'll just mention the easiest way I can think of to get started would be with open sourcing your scripts as a GitHub project and evolving them that way - you don't have to have everything I wrote about handled on day #1, and if you find the scripts helpful as-is then there may be some other people will as well.  Good luck :-)